# Is the joint probability of two sets equal to their intersection?

Tags: probability

This seems like a trivial question but somehow I have not been able to locate a source that will state that $$P(A\cap B) = P(A,B)$$.
Of course it is implied when conditional probabilities are stated as $$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A,B)}{P(B)}$$ and $$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$
I am missing anything?
Thanks for advice and apologies if necessary.

Comment: Here's an academic source: http://sites.nicholas.duke.edu/statsreview/probability/jmc/

Comment: Thanks very much.  Very helpful.  Quite obvious but somehow difficult to find in some textbooks.

Comment: Yes, I can guess why: an author would adopt one notation or the other, but probably not use both.  In my (quick) search I also found that the language of "joint" probability focuses on particular kinds of intersections rather than general intersections: joint probability is a concept attached to products of probability spaces whereas intersections make sense in all cases.

Comment: That is exactly where my doubts came from as I am trying to explain sets and probabilities to an audience that is not supposed to know any thing about probability theory so I thought that combining the explanation in a table of $P(A,B)$ with a Venn diagram that showed $P(\cap B)$ would be easier to understand it.

Comment: I always just saw these as two ways of notating the probability of an intersection, but I always preferred being explicit about the intersection with $\cap$.

Comment: The question posed in the title contains a category error. The intersection of two sets is a set, and a set is a different kind of object to a joint probability, so the joint probability of two sets cannot be their intersection -- it has to be a probability rather than a set. Please reword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: yes

Long answer: probability is just a measure of the likelihood of some set of events happening (e.g. a coin flip landing heads is the event, and the probability of this event for a fair coin is 0.5). So if you're looking at 2 sets that are exactly the same, namely A intersect B or A,B (although I find the latter notation a bit ambiguous), then their probabilities have to be the same. In general, it's a lot easier to think about events and how they relate, then using that to construct your probabilities.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, commas generally are used to denote intersection even by those who are otherwise very careful to avoid the possibility of their writings being misinterpreted. The most common usage is $P(X\leq 
x, Y \leq y)$ for the more prolix and correct $P\big ( (X \leq x)\cap (Y \leq y)\big)$ to denote the value of the joint CDF of random variables $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: My impression is that the use of the comma is when one is using tables in which case seems intuitive to express the joint probability of  row,column intersection as $P(r,c)$ whereas when dealing with diagrams  $P(A \cap B)$ seems more appropriate.